# sequence in analytical function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table  having column `name`

```
 NAME
=========
GAURAV
GAURAV
AJAY
AJAY
===========
```

Now i want to use an existing sequence ,let say abc_seq,and i want to group the records such that ,it will give me the output group by `name` and each group having the same sequence number

The output which i would like to get is shown below

```
name    group
==============
GAURAV    1
GAURAV    1
AJAY      2
AJAY      2
==============
```

I have tried this with analytical function ,but how to use sequence in the query having `analytical function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dense_rank` will do the work.

```
with t1 as
(
  select 'GAURAV' name from dual union all
  select 'GAURAV' name from dual union all
  select 'AJAY' name from dual union all
  select 'AJAY' name from dual
)

select name
     , dense_rank() over(order by name desc) rn
  from t1
```

Output:

```
Name    Rn 
-----------
GAURAV  1 
GAURAV  1 
AJAY    2 
AJAY    2
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4439f/2)

Answer (score 0):

select name,dense_rank() over ( order by name desc ) from table_name;

Just use dense_rank() analytical function , you can get the desired output.